# Linux localhost sockets painfully slower than on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, networking, sockets

This question is based on this thread over at [OpenOffice](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=74332).

I'm using Python and the [Office UNO bridge](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/module-ix.html) to analyze documents. For the most part I run on my Mac and spin up an office instance to listen on localhost:

```
soffice --accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
```

Using this, running through a test document takes about 2 seconds on my Mac. On Linux, however, that exact same scenario runs for about 45 seconds, a severe performance difference. And that's on Mint, Gentoo, and Ubuntu.

Interestingly, using office and connecting to it through a named pipe:

```
soffice --accept="pipe,name=abraxas;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
```

runs at pretty much the same speed on all tested platforms: about 1.5 seconds.

**Question**: what is so different between Mac and Linux socket connections, and why is the Linux socket so much slower?

Comment: Fixed in LibreOffice: https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/#/c/13856/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to [turn on TCP_NODELAY](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.16.shtml).

By default TCP uses [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) to collect small outgoing packets in order to send all at once as one big packet, which can have a detrimental effect on latency.

Comment: This worked great, and I've added `tcpNoDelay=1` to both sides of the connection. Thank you! Updated and resolved the [original thread](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=74332).

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing a similar behavior on my Ubuntu Desktop machine (so its not X related) where its taking ~45sec to complete.  Here are the biggest offenders based on an `strace` of the `soffice` process:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 68.50   23.948922         323     74067      1611 futex
 23.90    8.356000      151927        55           poll
  7.31    2.555215          95     26915           recv
  0.10    0.036301       18151         2           waitpid
  0.06    0.019407           2      9586           send
  0.05    0.016330          30       539        15 read
  0.03    0.009430           1     16675           gettimeofday
```

It looks to me like there might be some issues in how they implemented their thread synchronization in Linux.  I don't have access to a Mac to compare, but this is the command line I ran:

```
strace -cf soffice --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" --headless
```

Comment: See the answer above: add `tcpNoDelay=1` to both sides of the connection and performance will speed up tremendously.